# Win 2000 Terminal Server won't let users connect due to no licenses....?

Tags: rdp, terminal-server, windows-server-2000

I have an old Windows 2000 server in Terminal Server Application Mode which has recently started to issue errors to some users that the number of licenses has run out.

When I look into the Terminal Services Licensing tool I can see many old clients (some which I know to be long gone) and over 60 available licences.

I've tried the regedit (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSLicensing) to allow the everyone group read/write access but still no luck. Spent about a couple of hours googling to not find much.

Recently (within about the last week and a half) we SP4'd the server, so have a gut feeling its something to do with that but not sure.

Anyone seen anything like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue seems to be on the client side of the situation, the licensing certificate in the registry is corrupt and needs to be refreshed.

Detailed in kb:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315277

Answer (score 0):

Under administrative tools on the server check the licensing program.  If there are machines that are no longer in operation you can revoke their licenses, it may be that these clients have consumed all of the CALs that were available.

Comment: "No Licensing Logging service running", Licensing Applet tries to contact NT4 DC's for Licensing service...